# Send all outbound HTTP traffic from a rogue Wi-Fi router to an internal prank site

Tags: networking, router, iptables, dd-wrt

Today I discovered that my teenage son installed a rogue Wi-Fi router. It is plugged directly into the ethernet jack that I forgot was in his room. I assume he did it to bypass my internet schedule (and mild OpenDNS filtering). Rather than just ban the router by MAC address and maybe snip the ethernet cable at the box, I would like to scare him. While I am impressed with his skillz, I am disappointed that he opened up a no-password Wi-Fi AP to my network. I have a web site set up on a Raspberry Pi that says "you have been hacked...!" I want to forward all traffic coming from this router/access point to that Raspberry Pi web site.

I have so far failed in this endeavor. Here is my network:

- DD-WRT v24-sp2, running in Gateway mode (I have my ISP's router in DMZ mode sending everything to this one).

  `$uname -a
  Linux DD-WRT-1 3.11.10 #98 Sat Mar 1 21:51:43 CET 2014 mips GNU/Linux`
- The rogue router is a D-Link DIR-655. FWICT it serves addresses in the form of 192.168.0.*. He must have changed the default admin password.
- The D-Link is connected to the DD-WRT router via a hub that is a junction of all of the rooms in my house, but I am fine blocking them all: We don't (usually, lol) use them.
- I have the ethernet port that brings these ethernet ports into the DD-WRT router on its own VLAN (vlan3).
- I even gave the rogue router a static IP so I could always find it.

I have tried several variations of `iptables` commands, all of which I was sure would work. Here is the most promising, but it had no effect:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i vlan3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.65:80
```

- The D-Link router is on vlan3
- 10.0.0.65:80 is the internal IP of my Raspberry Pi webserver

I also tried doing this based on the MAC address of the D-Link router but it had no effect either. I have been running these iptables commands in a `ssh` session to the DD-WRT router.

Can anyone help me or direct me in the right direction? I have read several iptables docs and tutorials online but nothing seems to work. Do I need to redirect the 192.168.0.1/24 address range? I tried that but got no results at all. But perhaps I did it wrong:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.65
```

Comment: Whoops, that first iptables command should have been: `iptables -A PREROUTING -i vlan3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.65:80`

Comment: Just to be clear, your home's central hub connects to a LAN port on your DD-WRT box, and on the DD-WRT box you have that port configured as an unnumbered (untagged) interface that is internally mapped to vlan3? I want to make sure you aren't accidentally expecting the D-Link box to VLAN-tag its frames with VLAN ID 3. They're going to come in as non-VLAN-tagged frames; DD-WRT needs to consider all untagged incoming frames on that Ethernet port to be vlan3 frames.

Comment: I suspect if he's smart enough to figure out how to get a Wi-Fi router delivered without you knowing, set it up and have it broadcasting this long without you noticing, he's probably going to recognise an alert saying "you have been hacked" as bogus as well. Just my 2pennorth though. Internet filters just encourage the game of cat-and-mouse.

Comment: Spiff- you got it right. I may not have it right though :-).  Here is what I did: in the dd-wrt config: Setup -> VLANs -> set port 1 (which I assume is ethernet jack #1 on router) to #3. I did this to make it easy to tcpdump what he was doing on the network after school. Its probably an irrelevant detail.

Comment: seagull - thanks for your 2c. Yeah, I know. The site I set up is much cooler than that. He will freak out a bit.

Comment: idk why you're messing with iptables, that's a firewall.  You want to look into a  captive portal, or redirect all DNS queries to your raspberry pi, and then have a regular HTTP redirect to your webpage.  A DIY firewall might be a good way to do this, for example by using pfSense.  However, pfSense is meant for enterprise network admins, so if you can't find a tutorial, you might be out of luck.